# Why does Spring treat constructor injection differently than setter/field injection?

Tags: java, spring

I've come across a small problem with a circular dependency in project and found out that using `@Autowired` on a field/setter can fix that instead of using `@Autowired` on a constructor. The conclusion of such behavior is that Spring injects proxies in the case of field/setter injections, and actual beans in the case of constructor injection.

The question:
What is the reasoning behind this? Why different entities are injected?

Consider simple snippet:

```
    @Component
    public static class A{
        @Autowired B b;
        @Autowired C c;
    }
    @Component
    public static class B{
        @Autowired B b;
        @Autowired C c;
//      public B(C c,B b) { // this would cause circular dep problem
//          this.c=c;
//      }
    }
    @Component
    public static class C{
        @Autowired A a;
        @Autowired B b;
    }
```

One of ideas that comes into my mind is that with constructor injection, you are able to use injected entities right away, thus as a precaucion initialized beans are injected instead of proxies but on the other hand, I can do the same in case of setter approach, so that seams to be invalid.

Comment: Have you proved that it is a proxy? It should be easy enough to do: just print thing.getClass().getName().

Comment: I don't think that proxy matter at all here. According to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-dependency-resolution) it is simply **false** that constructor injection and setter injection are equivalent. Period. In constructor injection it is expected that the arguments are fully constructed, but this is simply *impossible* when circular dependencies arise. Hence they decided to simply make it an error. In setter injection you know that the argument may not be completely constructed when passed as an argument.

Comment: @rghome maybe not, that is just mine conclusion. Moreover i think it is a proxy as it has null fields an is of "enhanced" class. Whatever it is proxy or not, behavior is confirmed. I just would like to know the reasoning behind this

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta thanks for pointing out the documentation. Its funny how much of knowledge is threre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you used constructor injection all beans which are used in constructor must be created earlier. If you have circular dependencies then they can not be created because of this cirular dependencies and spring throw exception.

When you use setter/field injection injected element are set after creation of bean, so cirular depenecies are allowed.

BTW if you have circular dependecies try to redesign you application, because your code will be harder to maintain. It's one of reason why constructor injection should be preferred.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, and the most important part here is the point int time of WHEN injection happens - in case of field/setters all injections are done AFTER every bean instance is created which might not be possible in case of ctor.